# MYSQL | Query to Get Leaves Allocated and Leaves Taken for Employee and should show the category of leave

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

Trying to solve this mystery from morning and its like i am banging my head over the brick wall.

Let me give you some background.

Employees will be allocated leaves in different Category e-g sick etc etc..

Now if an employee want to take leave he will submit the application which then will be approved by someone.

Now here comes my part where i want to get the records and show it on page, i want to get which employee took how many leaves and how many leaves was assigned to him/her but i have to show those leaves in a category base, depends on the category it is assigned.

it is confusing so i will put schema screenshots.

[image]

This is the query i have tried so far.. but the problem in this query is i am getting the total leaves taken as total general, i mean it counts all the category leaves. where as it should show how many leaves employee has taken in which category

```
SELECT 
E.employee_id, 
E.full_name, 
LE.no_of_leaves AS AllocatedLeaves,
MLLT.leave_type AS LeaveTypeName,
MLLT.`ml_leave_type_id` AS LeaveTypeID, 
IFNULL(LA.TotalLeavesTaken,0) AS TotalLeavesTaken, 
(LE.no_of_leaves - IFNULL(LA.TotalLeavesTaken,0)) AS balance
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN leave_entitlement LE ON E.employee_id = LE.employee_id AND MONTH(LE.`date_approved`) = 11
LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLT ON MLLT.ml_leave_type_id = LE.ml_leave_type_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT LA.employee_id, COUNT(1) AS TotalLeavesTaken , LA.`leave_application_id`
           FROM leave_approval LA 
           WHERE MONTH(LA.approval_date) = 11
           GROUP BY LA.employee_id
         ) AS LA ON E.employee_id = LA.employee_id
LEFT JOIN leave_application LAPP ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id
LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLTLA ON MLLTLA.ml_leave_type_id = LAPP.ml_leave_type_id
WHERE E.`employee_id` = 1
GROUP BY E.employee_id,LeaveTypeName;
```

result i am getting for the query is 
[image]

If you see total leaves taken for employee_id =`1` is `2` for both leaveTypeIDs where as it is different in the below table screenshot

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between the number of leaves they took and the number of leaves assigned to them? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
E.employee_id, 
E.full_name, 
LE.no_of_leaves AS AllocatedLeaves,
MLLT.leave_type AS LeaveTypeName,
MLLT.`ml_leave_type_id` AS LeaveTypeID, 
IFNULL(LA.TotalLeavesTaken,0) AS TotalLeavesTaken, 
(LE.no_of_leaves - IFNULL(LA.TotalLeavesTaken,0)) AS balance
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN leave_entitlement LE ON E.employee_id = LE.employee_id AND MONTH(LE.`date_approved`) = 11
LEFT JOIN ml_leave_type MLLT ON MLLT.ml_leave_type_id = LE.ml_leave_type_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT LA.employee_id, COUNT(1) AS TotalLeavesTaken , LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`
           FROM leave_approval LA 
           INNER JOIN leave_application LAPP ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id
           WHERE MONTH(LA.approval_date) = 11
           GROUP BY LA.employee_id, LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id` 
         ) AS LA ON E.employee_id = LA.employee_id AND LA.`ml_leave_type_id` = LE.ml_leave_type_id
WHERE E.`employee_id` = 1
GROUP BY E.employee_id, LeaveTypeName;
```